# TypeError: $ is not a function at jQuery function

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a simple jQuery script in a WordPress plugin that is using a jQuery wrapper:

```
$("#myForm").submit(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    if ($('input[name="username"]').val() == "" || $('input[name="password"]').val() == "") 

        $("#NotesArea").html("Please enter both Username and Passnumber");

    else

        $.post($(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize())

              .done(function(data)              { $("#NotesArea").html(data); })

              .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );});

});
```

I am calling this script from within the WordPress Dashboard and i am getting always this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function

Alright, I made it like this, no errors but the code doesn't work!

```
(function($){
$("#myForm").submit(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    if ($('input[name="username"]').val() == "" || $('input[name="password"]').val() == "") 

        $("#NotesArea").html("Please enter both Username and Passnumber");

    else

        $.post($(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize())

              .done(function(data)              { $("#NotesArea").html(data); })

              .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );});

});
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: it seems like jquery conflicts because of two different version is used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wordpress use noConflict which removes the `$` alias

Wrap your code in the following IIFE and you can continue using `$` inside it

```
(function($){
  /* your code*/

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I made it like what you have suggested, but it won't work! see y edit plz.

Comment: *"doesn't work"* isn't very informative. Does the submit event get triggered? does that ajax request get made? Need more detail

Comment: "ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined" this was the error!

Comment: Then either jQuery.js isn't loaded or your script is being included before jQuery.js. Are you using proper `wordpress wp_enqueue_script()` for this?

Answer (score 2):

jQuery is in compatibility mode, use "jQuery" instead of "$".

https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/adding-jquery-scripts-wordpress/

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you call jquery library BEFORE your script.

Comment: 'sure' not 'shure'