# Plugin is causing error in theme JS file when activated

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I have installed a plugin called Flexible Products Fields, but apparently it is causing errors in the JS code of the theme

The images disappear and also the attributes can't be selected.. I checked the console and it showed me the error

Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function

which is refering to this code

```
$(function(){
$('.carousel').carousel();
$('.shre-top a ,.lang-top a ,[data-placement] ').tooltip();

});
```

I tried fixing this issue after some google search by doing this but got the same error

```
(function($){
$('.carousel').carousel();
$('.shre-top a ,.lang-top a ,[data-placement] ').tooltip();

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: $ is not a function at jQuery function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39882726/typeerror-is-not-a-function-at-jquery-function)

Comment: I tried that before I posted this question and it didn't work

Comment: just try to initialize `$ = jQuery` in a head section before starting of jquery